# How to display user/account profile icon in VsCode display, and add my account to it?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[Vscode image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBj9f.jpg)

I tried looking for a setting for it and watching some videos but none of them were  specific and i'm kind of new to the it. I want the user icon to show where the red mark is, it was okay until I tried to add my account to it. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Right-click just above the area and make sure `Accounts` is enabled.